# _fullpath() doesn't work correctly with long relative paths

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've got a problem with a customer using fairly long paths combined with some relative pathing.

Essentially, the current directory is less than _MAX_PATH, the relative path to a file is less than _MAX_PATH, and the absolute path derived from the relative path is less than _MAX_PATH.

But the current directory concatenated with the relative path is greater than _MAX_PATH, and so the call fails and returns 0.

Does anyone know a way around this? Do we need to write our own relative-to-absolute path algorithm that isn't so naive?

Here's some example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char base_dir[] =     "C:\\directory_location_1\\directory_location_2\\directory_location_3\\directory_location_4\\directory_location_5\\directory_location_6\\directory_location_7\\directory_location_8\\";
    const char rel_path[] =     "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\directory_location4\\directory_location5\\directory_location6\\directory_location7\\test.txt";
    _chdir(base_dir);

    char abs_path[1024] = "";
    _fullpath(abs_path, rel_path, 1024);

    printf("base_dir length: %d\n", strlen(base_dir));
    printf("rel_path length: %d\n", strlen(rel_path));
    printf("base_dir + rel_path length: %d\n", strlen(base_dir) + strlen(rel_path));
    printf("abs_path length: %d\n", strlen(abs_path));
    printf("Path: %s", abs_path);

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the output:

```
base_dir length: 171
rel_path length: 103
base_dir + rel_path length: 274
abs_path length: 0
Path:
```

Something to note, I couldn't even execute `cd ..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\directory_location4\\directory_location5\\directory_location6\\directory_location7\\` from directory_location_8 (it says "The filename or extension is too long."), so this seems pretty low-level in the Windows API.

Anyone have a reliable relative path -> absolute path algorithm for Windows?

Comment: Pre-Windows 8 there is nothing you can do (except for rolling your own). Starting with Windows 8 you can use [PathCchAppendEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707082.aspx) and [PathCchCanonicalizeEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707084.aspx) to construct the final path. Both APIs support paths longer than `MAX_PATH`. You should also definitely consider using Unicode.

Comment: Maybe use extended length paths https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath.

Comment: What version of Windows? On my Windows 7 I get: `abs_path length: 91
Path: C:\directory_location4\directory_location5\directory_location6\directory_location7\test.txt`

Comment: @drescherjm Can't use extended-length paths with relative paths, unfortunately. I had hoped that would help, but I don't know if there's any way to get relative pathing working with extended-length paths.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Hmm, that's odd. I'm on Windows 7 as well. Not sure what the difference in our systems might be... But if you've got some setup that allows this to work, I'd like to replicate it!